# How to solve $x'=3x+sin(2t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a rough idea of how to solve this nonautonomous equation.

$x'=3x+sin(2t)$

$\int 1\, dx=\int (3x+sin(2t))\, dt$

$x = 3xt - \frac{cos(2t)}{2} + constant$

$(1-3t)x = -\frac{1}{2}cos(2t) +constant$

$x = -\frac{cos(2t)}{2(1-3t)}+\frac{constant}{1-3t}$

Does this look right?

Comment: No it looks wrong, just for the fact that there is a vertical asymptote at $t=1/3$, which isn't possible with this linear  ODE. You don't seem to know the theory behind this.

Comment: Your mistake is to consider $x$ a constant when integrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as

$$x'-3x=e^{3t}(e^{-3t}x)'=\sin2t,$$

then

$$x=e^{3t}\int e^{-3t}\sin2t\,dt.$$

To evaluate the integral, work by parts, twice, or switch to complex exponentials.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not correct. This is a [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation). Note that
$$x'(t)-3x(t)=\sin(2t)\implies 
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-3t}x(t)\right)=e^{-3t}(x'(t)-3x(t))=e^{-3t}\sin(2t).$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is
$$x=x_c+x_p$$
$x_c$ when the D.E is homogeneouse
so
$$x'=3x$$
$$\frac{x'}{x}=3$$
integrate it
$$\log|x|=3t+c$$
or
$$x=ke^{3t}$$
to find the particular solution, let
$$x_p=A\sin 2t+B\cos 2t$$
substitute in the original D.E to find $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0):

By educated guess, the solution might be a sum of complex exponentials of the form

$$x=e^{zt}$$ where $z$ is a constant.

Plugging in the equation,

$$(z-3)e^{zt}=\frac{e^{i2t}-e^{-i2t}}{2i}=\frac{e^{i2t}}{2i}-\frac{e^{-i2t}}{2i}+0.$$

By identification, the solution will have terms with $z=2i$ and $z=-2i$. We also note that a term with $z=3$ brings a $0$ contribution. Hence,

$$x=\frac{e^{i2t}}{2i(2i-3)}-\frac{e^{-i2t}}{2i(-2i-3)}+Ce^{3z}.$$

The final expression can be rewritten with trigonometric functions, using reals only.